# Is it possible to view the images used in the site themes?

Tags: support, design

How would I access the theme of a Stack Exchange site?

I am particularly interested in the map in the background of the [Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/).

Is there a way to view and/or save the theme/image?

Comment: Right clicking on it? Then inspect element or save the image.

Comment: Press `[F12]` or `[Ctrl]+[I]`, and find the tab in the dev tools that lists all media in use in the page.

Comment: [map image](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/travel/img/bg-map.png?v=78dabedcf17b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by using the developer tools of your browser.

**One way of accomplishing this.**
The exact way depends on the browser you use, but in most modern browsers you can right-click an element and select *Inspect Element* to open the developer tools and focus on the element under your cursor. This is a direct way to find the image, as you can point and click on it.

Doing this on the Travel Stack Exchange front page leads us to discover a CSS rule that sets the background image to [this one](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/travel/img/bg-map.png). For completes, at the time of writing the rule is

```css
.container {
    background: url('img/bg-map.png?v=78dabedcf17b') no-repeat center -34px;
}
```

The background color is set on the `body` element, and is `#18748a` for the same site.

**An alternative way.**
As mentioned by [Cerbrus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1835379), there is an easy alternative way of finding images in Chrome. This method will save you from looking through CSS rules. Instead, you can find *all* images loaded on a page.

1. [Open](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/#open) the developer tools in Chrome by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> or opening *More Tools* > *Developer Tools* from the main menu of Chrome.
2. Focus the *Application* tab.
3. In the left panel of that tab, open *Frames*, then *top*, then *Images*.
4. Find the image you are interested in, save it if desired.

[image: Screenshot displaying the result of executing the above steps on the background image of Travel Stack Exchange's front page]

Comment: An easier way is the "Application" tab in Chrome dev tools. Under "Frames", there's a tree that shows you, among other things, all images loaded into a site.

Comment: Thanks @Cerbrus, I included that method in my answer.